# How to cut image into pieces, randomize them and put all together

Tags: image, bash

I want to cut an image (orig.jpg) into 16px x 16px pieces, randomize their order and put them to a new image (jpg) of same size together. Basically a mosaic effect, but with no order.

The splitting is not the problem

```
convert -crop 16x16@ orig.jpg  tile_%d.jpg
```

but I have no clue how to randomly put them together...

```
montage
```

should do the trick I guess. I did it before, but cannot find the script :-S

The use of all: I need images with exact the same colors and brightness, but it shouldn't be possible to recognize the original image.

Comment: This is a statement more like a problem description - what are you using in Python and what is your data type? Show us something and also what you have tried so far!

Comment: You're not gonna get a complete solved example here. What have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: What's the point of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this with `bash` and `ImageMagick`:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -crop 16x16@ input.jpg tile.jpg
montage -geometry +0+0 $(ls tile*jpg | awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand() "\t" $0}' | sort -n | cut -f2-) output.png

# Remember to remove the tile*jpg before you do another one :-)
# rm tile*jpg
```

Basically as you suggest, using `-crop` and `montage`. The bit inside `$()` is *process substitution* and it takes the result of running the process inside the parentheses and puts it into the `montage` command. It lists all files called `tile*jpg` and pipes that into `awk` to append a random number to the front of each file, then it sorts by the random number and chops it off.

So it makes this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

I have been experimenting further with this (i.e. *playing around*) and I see you can get white lines and gaps between the tiles. I am not sure if these bother you, but if they do, a possible solution is to note the original image geometry and then resize it to an exact multiple of your 16x16 tile-size. Then proceed as before, and resize by the odd 0-15 pixels at the end, back to the original size.

If that is necessary, I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get original image geometry
origgeom=$(identify -format %g input.jpg)
echo $origgeom
# Calculate new geometry as exact multiple of tilesize
newgeom=$(convert input.jpg -format "%[fx:int(w/16)*16]x%[fx:int(h/16)*16]" info:)
echo $newgeom

# Resize to new geometry and tile
convert input.jpg -resize $newgeom -crop 16x16@ tile.jpg

# Rebuild in random order then correct geometry
montage -background none -geometry +0+0 $(ls tile*jpg | awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand() "\t" $0}' | sort -n | cut -f2-) JPG:- | convert JPG: -resize ${origgeom}! output.jpg
```

[image]